# Access file as Sudo

Tags: c#, xamarin.mac

How can I read a file as sudo/admin on Mac in C# (xamarin.Mac)

I made a File in /usr/
and I cant read it with:

```
string text = system.io.file.ReadallText("/usr/file");
```

it doesn't seam to have access to the file.

EDIT:
It needs to be from within the Program

Comment: `sudo <yourprogram>`?

Comment: Check for directory permissions

Comment: If you could access files (without user intervention) that you do not have access to it wouldn't be a very secure operating system IMO. It sounds to me like you have a design flaw in your program. Either write to a folder that you are allowed to access or elevate your program to read an otherwise inaccessible file.

Comment: I cant find anything in the Xamarin Guide how to Elevate the Program. is it from the info.plist?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html